# "error":"unsupported_grant_type" - Volley

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I use the volley library to execute the POST method.

I send the username, password and grant_type like parameters of JsonObjectRequest but I But I receive the following error: "error: unsupported_grant_type".

Tried but can't really see where I'm going wrong.

How can I solve that?

Here is my code:

Kotlin

```
val url: String = "http://192.168.254.80/MpDS/api/token"
val params = HashMap<String, String>()


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    /*LOGIN BUTTON*/
    BLogin = findViewById(R.id.LoginButton)
    BLogin?.setOnClickListener(this)
}

fun login() {

    params.put("UserName", userTxt.toString())
    params.put("Password", passTxt.toString())
    params.put("grant_type", "password")

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)
    val response: String? = null

    val req = JsonObjectRequest(url, JSONObject(params),
            Response.Listener { response ->
                try {
                    VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4))
                    textView.text = "work!"
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }, Response.ErrorListener {
                error -> VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.message

            )
    })

    fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {

        val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        return headers
    }

    queue.add(req)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
post.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=password&username=0000@gmail.com&password=00000", "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't solve the problem because this is to be used with httpClient and I'm currently with volley. Could be something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I can not add comments because my reputation does not allow it :( so this is the answer link:  [WebAPI call using volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227433/webapi-call-using-volley)

and this is the implementation in my android project to get the token (I use Asp.net web API with Owin)

```
 public void GetToken(final UserAccount userAccount)
{

    String url = "http://localhost:8081/token";

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Log.e("TOKEN_AUTH", response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.e("KL", error.networkResponse.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String> ();
            params.put("grant_type", "password");
            params.put("username", userAccount.getEmail());
            params.put("password", userAccount.getPassword());
            return params;
        }
        @Override
        protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError response) {
            try {

                String json = new String(response.networkResponse.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.networkResponse.headers));
                Log.e("KL", "ERROR_RESPONSE = " + json);
            }catch (Exception e){}
            return super.parseNetworkError(response);
        }
    };

    //Add to resquestQueue
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
}
```

**Logcat console**

[image]

Comment: Is a answer man, edit: oh no he use kotlin And the code is Java :(